# Is an electron wave just a particle in superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am just getting into quantum mechanics so forgive me if my question is misguided, but regarding the double slit experiment, when an electron is fired and acts as a wave, is the wave just a superposition of the different possible places the particle could be? And when observed, the wave collapses/forces the particle into a definite position? Does the probability function of where the electron will land on the screen also collapse into 1 spike because the electron can only land in one place?

Comment: The probability function is the squared magnitude of the wavefunction. So anything which looks like a collapse from our point of view happens to both of them. And yes, wavefunctions that don't yield a definite location are superpositions of wavefunctions that do.

Comment: Nobody can seriously give a good answer of what is going on here, as it pertains to the “measurement problem” that is one of the great unsolved problems in physics. But nevertheless, under the Copenhagen interpretation you can interpret this as the electron wavefunction becoming far more localized due to interaction with some macroscopic detector. By the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, this means the uncertainty in momentum increases, and the De Broglie’s wavelength will be altered in turn. This can be interpreted to cause the erasure of the diffraction pattern.

Comment: One thing that took me a while to get my head around is that the wavefunction is not like a normal wave that propagates through a medium or field. The wavefunction is not a "sound wave" or an "electromagnetic wave." In a way you can think of it as a "probability wave" -- the (modulus squared of the) wave function is the probability distribution to find the electron at any given location. So, when the wavefunction is spread out, the electron is in a superposition of being found at different locations. When the wave function is sharply peaked, the electron is effectively localized near the peak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "wave" we are talking about can be mathematically understood as a superposition of a bunch of states with the electron having a completely determinate location, albeit with some technical caveats regarding the implied calling of such things "states".

Superposition is actually not some special property, but rather simply the fact of linear combinability of vectors. Every Hilbert vector can be written as the superposition of at least two other such vectors. To make this a little more evocative, when Schrodinger's famous, mythical cat is ruled to be in one of the *ordinary* states known as "alive" or "dead", we can *equivalently* call *this* situation a superposition of two of the "bizarre" states of the kind that generate all the controversy. The controversy is all around how should we best physically interpret those "bizarre" states.

(In electron terms, this means we can also understand a state with more-determinate location as a superposition of "weird" states of less-determinate location.)

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90: Fair.